# How to properly pass an attribute from parent custom element to child custom element?

Tags: svelte, web-component, custom-element

**ParentCustomElement.svelte**

```
<svelte:options tag="parent-custom-element" />

<script>
  import ChildCustomElement from "./ChildCustomElement.svelte";
  let greeting = "Hello";
</script>

<child-custom-element greeting="{greeting}"></child-custom-element>
```

**ChildCustomElement.svelte**

```
<svelte:options tag="child-custom-element" />

<script>
  export let greeting;
  /* within the script scope "greeting" is undefined */
  console.log(greeting);
</script>

<!-- within the template scope "greeting" is defined ("hello") -->
<p>{greeting}</p>
```

What I need is access to the attribute value within the script scope to do some magic and only after that load the template. How to do this?

Comment: Have you tried [`onMount`](https://svelte.dev/docs#run-time-svelte-onmount)?

Comment: Yes, I did. But then the template is rendered before the script is ready.

Comment: Well, you can add a local flag to indicate when it is done and use `{#if}` around the template.

Comment: Could you provide a short example?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably can use `onMount` like this:

```html
<script>
  import { onMount } from 'svelte';

  export let greeting;

  let initialized = false;
  onMount(() => {
    // [use greeting for whatever]

    initialized = true;
  });
</script>

{#if initialized}
  ...
{/if}
```

Comment: If I do an assignment like `let temp = greeting;` within `onMount` and then use `temp` within the template, it is `undefined`. Why is this?

Comment: If there is a `let` in `onMount`, that variable will be [scoped](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Scope) to that function and cannot be used outside of it.